# C# Word Interop Hyperlinks not appearing

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, word-interop

I have a Mergefield called SiteLink which contains a url and looks like this { MERGEFIELD SiteLink }

This is my code to replace SiteLink with a URL during a mail merge. However, when I run it, the document generated does not display a link.

```
private void InsertHyperlinkToField(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document Document, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range Range, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Field MyMergeField, Object Missing, string FieldText, string FieldName, string MergeValue, string HyperlinkLabel)
{
    if (FieldText.StartsWith(" MERGEFIELD"))
    {
        //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range range = MyMergeField.Code;
        string fieldName = FieldText.Remove(0, 11);
        fieldName = fieldName.Trim();
        if (fieldName == FieldName)
        {
            MyMergeField.Select();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Hyperlink hl = Document.Hyperlinks.Add(Range, MergeValue, Missing, Missing, HyperlinkLabel, Missing);
        }
    }
}
```

What is the proper way to mail merge a hyperlink?

Comment: Looks like you are just assigning to a local variable: hl and nothing more??

Comment: @siggi_pop, how do i replace a mergefield with this variable?